# WordPress hook directly after body tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having problems finding the right hook to use for my plugin. I'm trying to add a message to the top of each page by having my plugin add a function. What's the best hook to use? I want to insert content right after the `<body>` tag.

---

EDIT: I know it's three years later now, but here is a [Trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac) ticket for anyone who is interested: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12563

---

**EDIT: July 31st, 2019**

The linked [Trac Ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12563) was closed as this feature was added in WordPress 5.2. You will find the Developer notes for this feature here (requires JavaScript enabled to display):

*[Miscellaneous Developer Updates in 5.2](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/04/24/miscellaneous-developer-updates-in-5-2/)*

I will not update the "correct answer" to one that mentions 5.2 for historical reasons, but rest assured that I'm aware and that the built-in  hook is the correct one to use.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.maltpress.co.uk/2010/10/05/wordpress-injecting-code-after-the-body-tag-for-plugins/

Comment: @helbetica suggested this link may help http://hookr.io/

Comment: There is a hack that does it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/317892/152412
Filtering body classes to add 'class' that is kind of injecting HTML code into the `body class` attribute.

Comment: One of best answers I've seen to this question is: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219931/insert-html-just-after-body-tag/219938#219938

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## WordPress 5.2 or newer:

Use the [wp_body_open](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_body_open/) hook.

## WordPress 5.1 or older:

That's kinda difficult... Most themes don't have any hooks in that area. You could hook a javascript/html solution into `wp_footer` and display it at the top of the page... sort of how Stack Overflow does it, or how Twitter does their notifications.

This is the best reference for all the hooks included in WordPress:
http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/

Answer (score 40):

Alternatively, if you are creating the theme yourself and/or can modify it, you can create an action yourself using WordPress' [`do_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) function. This is also how they create their other hooks. So basically in your theme, you would go where you want to, right after the `<body>` tag, and do something like:

```
do_action('after_body');
```

You can also pass arguments to the action callback, see the linked documentation for information.

Then afterwards, you would simply use the [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) function to hook onto it.

```
add_action('after_body', 'my_callback');
```

Hope that helps. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: The concept makes sense the problem is I'm trying to display an optional notification at the top of the page of any theme inside of WordPress.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. If a person writes a custom theme, he doesn't need the hook in the first place.

Answer (score 18):

Creating custom hook is really easy in WordPress.
in `header.php` (or anywhere you may need a hook) locate:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="body-container">
```

and make it:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php body_begin(); ?>
<div id="body-container">
```

That's our hook, now let's make it work.
In `functions.php` add:

```
function body_begin() {
do_action('body_begin');
}
```

Now hook is ready to use, simply add any actions you need in `functions.php`:

```
function my_function() {
/* php code goes here */
}
add_action('body_begin', 'my_function');
```

or JavaScript (tracking code etc - this is not the perfect way though, it is a better practice to load JavaScript from `.js` files, but it is definitely better than adding JavaScript directly to template files):

```
function my_function() { ?>
<script>
<!-- JavaScript goes here --!>
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('body_begin', 'my_function');
```

Comment: Very useful answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Changes, changes, changes. So it appears that since March 2019 (from WP 5.2) we have a little nicer way to do this.

There is a new function [`wp_body_open()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_body_open/). To support it, your theme has to call this function right after `<body>` opening tag:

```
<html>
  <head>

    ..
    ..

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

  </head>
  <body>

    <?php wp_body_open(); ?>

    ..
    ..

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

And then you can use it in the same way you use `wp_head` or `wp_footer` hooks to print anything just after `<body>`.

Answer (score 4):

I searched the internet for answers to the same question but found nothing. I figured out away to  to work around it. My plugin [infinite Ad Pay](https://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-ad-pay/developers/) is based on this method.

You need two hooks 
**wp_head** and **wp_footer** hook

```html
 

add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_buffer_holder_fxn');

function my_buffer_holder_fxn(){
ob_start()


}


function my_buffer_pour_out_fxn(){

$get_me_buffers  = ob_get_clean();

$pattern ='/<[bB][oO][dD][yY]\s[A-Za-z]{2,5}[A-Za-z0-9 "_=\-\.]+>|<body>/';
ob_start();
if(preg_match($pattern, $get_me_buffers, $get_me_buffers_return)){


$d_new_body_plus =$get_me_buffers_return[0]."<div class='my_below_body_code'> This is below the body text or image or anything you want </div>";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $d_new_body_plus, $get_me_buffers);

}
ob_flush();
}



}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_buffer_pour_out_fxn');


// You can also use the method above to place anything in other sections of WordPress 
//No Javascript used
```

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, what i do is: Use Jquery to append or prepend things:

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: what if you want to load more javascript after the body tag? like facebook js sdk?

Answer (score 1):

A very, very, very dirty solution would be:

```
/* Insert tracking code or others directly after BODY opens */
add_filter('body_class', 'wps_add_tracking_body', PHP_INT_MAX); // make sure, that's the last filter in the queue
function wps_add_tracking_body($classes) {

  // close <body> tag, insert stuff, open some other tag with senseless variable      
  $classes[] = '"><script> /* do whatever */ </script><noscript></noscript novar="';

  return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Dirty indeed! Nice trick with the `PHP_INT_MAX` - that's a key part of this solution.  Your class MUST be the last one, otherwise this could be disasterous!

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any working example online, but I got one solution and I hope it might help anyone. It is quite simple, just add jquery and do whatever you want. The below example might help anyone.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
$('body').prepend('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});
```

Here is the website url 
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add_action-right-after-ltbodygt-tag

With the help of the above answer, I have made a plugin which directly adds content after the body tag.
Here is the sample code :

```
var wcs_thankyou_msg =  " Your coupon code is <?php echo $post_title; ?>."+"<?php echo get_option('wcs_thankyou_msg'); ?>"

var wcs_scratch_after_text =  "<?php  echo $wcs_scratch_after_text;?>"

var discount_text = "<?php  echo $post_excerpt;?>"

var offer_message = "<?php echo get_option('wcs_offer_text'); ?>" 

var id = "<?php echo $post_id; ?>"



$('body').prepend('<div id="scratch_main"><div class="scratch_open">'+offer_message+'</div><div id="scratchmain" style="overflow:hidden;"><div class="scratchinnermain"><div class="scratch_text"><div class="scratch_close"></div><div class="scratchtxtstl">'+wcs_top_text+'</div><div class="scratchtxtstl2">'+wcs_top_text_h2+'</div><div id="wscratchpad" class="scratch_img"><div id="scratchBg" class="scratchpad"></div><div class="scratch_offer" style="display:none">'+discount_text+'</div></div></div><div class="scratch_form"><div id="thankYouDiv" style="display:none"><div class="scratch_close"></div><div class="form_txt1">'+wcs_thankyou_msg+'</div></div><div class="scratchinnermain" id="scratchinnermain" style="display:none"><div class="form_txt1">'+wcs_scratch_after_text+'</div><div class="scratch_form_main"><div id="returnmessage"></div><div id="ajax-loading-wp">Sending, Please wait...</div><form id="mycontactform" action="" method="post"><div class="clear_input"><div class="label">Name :</div><div class="wc_input"><input id="name" type="text" name="name"/></div></div><div class="clear_input"><div class="label">Email :</div><div class="wc_input"><input id="email" type="text" name="email"/><input id="submit" type="button" value="send" class="register_btn"/></div></div></form></div></div></div></div></div></div>');

});
```

The most amazing thing is that I don't know how I have done the above code in an easy way, pulling the data dynamic right after the body tag. I hope my answer will help someone and give a better idea.
Live working example : http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-coupon-scratch-discount/9235287

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has now addressed this by adding the [wp_body_open](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_body_open/) hook in version 5.2. You can now hook or inject into HTML body by doing:

```
<?php add_action('wp_body_open', function() { //some code to fire or inject HTML here }); ?>
```

Putting this in your functions.php file in your theme might be best for most basic users.

Comment: It looks like it might be wp_body_open, not wp_body. Can you confirm that?

Comment: yes I confirmed that Pikamander2 is right and Krzysiek Dróżdż answer is correct