# Insert HTML after opening <body> tag in WordPress's admin pages

Tags: php, wordpress, action, customization

I am adding a WordPress network to an existing website and one of my requirements is to embed the admin utility within our existing sites' layout.

I've written a custom plugin that registers functions to the `admin_head` and `admin_footer` actions. `admin_head` inserts content inside the `<head>` tag and `admin_footer` inserts content near the end of the `<body>` section.

Is there another action that inserts content immediately after the `<body>` tag or just before any visible HTML is output by WordPress?

Thanks!

Comment: There is an answer for this here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581510/wordpress-hook-directly-after-body-tag

Comment: Actually, your link refers to the publicly facing part of WordPress and I'm asking about the admin section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wordpress 5.2.0 introduced the `wp_body_open` hook (detailed in the [WordPress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_body_open/))

```
// Add code after opening body tag.
add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'wpdoc_add_custom_body_open_code' );
 
function wpdoc_add_custom_body_open_code() {
    echo '<!-- custom code -->';
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for WordPress admin.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a hook/filter that you can use. The best you can do is to use admin_footer.

**Edit**: I was going through the [admin-header.php](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-admin/admin-header.php) and found an action **in_admin_header**

Try it. I am not sure if this will solve you problem though.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't found anything since I asked the question either. :/

Comment: Sadly, in_admin_header is called inside wp-content, meaning that the adminmenu and a few containing classes have already been output. My goal is to wrap the WordPress admin section in a container. Any other ideas?