# How to read a function in the header file? [Wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress, function, header

I am writing a wordpress plugin and I want to insert a function just after the `<body>` tag in the source.

My functions looks like this :

```
function skew() {
    ?>

    <?
}
add_action ('hook_name', 'skew');
```

What hook should I use to make this function run just after body tag? Or is there any other simpler method to make  this run just after opening the body tag? Thanks.

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581510/wordpress-hook-directly-after-body-tag

Answer (score 0):

Use add_action and do_action functions as below:

do_action('after_body');
add_action('after_body', 'skew');