# How to get product data in header.php file wordpress woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show something of product like: `name`, `price`, `sku` in the `header.php` file.
Below is my code to get product in header.php

```
global $product;
var_dump($product);
```

But var_dump just show me the product name like `string(6) "hoodie"`, not array of product.

So, how can I get the product data in header.php file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Wordpress **`get_the_ID()`** function.

- [Wordpress - get_the_ID()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/)

Obviously this will only work if you are on the product page, so you can add an extra control with WooCommerce's `is_product()` function.

- [WooCommerce - is_product()](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-conditional-functions.html#source-view.83)

Finally, to add custom code in the header you can use the `wp_head` hook.

- [Wordpress - wp_head](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/)

So the function will look like:

```
// gets the product data in the header
add_action( 'wp_head', 'get_product_data' );
function get_product_data() {
    // only on the product page
    if ( ! is_product() ) {
        return;
    }
    // gets the product object
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
    ?>
    HTML CODE HERE
    <?php
}
```

*Tested and it works. The code goes into your active theme's functions.php file.*

Comment: But `wp_head` is generate code in the `<head></head>` tag. That is not good, The head tag is meant for metadata, not for building elements.

Comment: Can I write your function as a custom hook, then do_action to the body tag in header.php file?

Comment: Sure. It was not specified in the question but it is assumed that you want to insert meta tags with the product data inside the head tag. Also because, if different tags are added, the browser will display it inside the body tag. For the hook in the body you can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581510/wordpress-hook-directly-after-body-tag